# Является ли хэш-функция последовательной?

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры

Как я понимаю, Hashtable не допускает null ключи и null значения.
Значит всегда есть пара: ключ,значение и по ключу мы можем получить значение. Получается, что эта хэш-функция всегда будет возвращать ложь? В книге "Грокаем алгоритмы" эта функция непоследовательна, при одинаковых входных данных получаем разные значения. Но почему?

```
f(x)= has_empty_slot()
```

Comment: Последовательная - это детерминированная или что имеется в виду? Хэш-функция должна давать одинаковый результат при одинаковых аргументах, да. Понятия ключ-значение применимо к словарям. При чём тут хэш-функция? У функции есть аргументы и есть результат - такова общепринятая терминология. "Эта хэш-функция" - это какая? `has_empty_slot()`? А что это за функция, вы не привели её содержимое, как мы можем судить о её свойствах? И если функция всегда возвращает ложь, то это детерминированная функция: она при одинаковых агрументах (или их отстуствии) возвращает одинаковый результат. У вас мешанина.

Comment: Кстати, `print(hash(None))` выдаёт конкретное значение, не ругается. Так что что там за `null`-ы такие, которые не допустимы - тоже непонятно.

Comment: Вопрос следует задавать так, чтобы его суть была понятна на основании только текста вопроса. Ваш вопрос без чтения "Грокаем алгоритмы" вообще не понятен. Что за функция has_empty_slot() ? На основании каких входных данных она выдаёт разные значения, если в вашем примере она вообще никаких входных данных не принимает?

Comment: Если вместо х мы подставим любой ключ из хэш-таблицы, будет ли он выдавать каждый раз один и тот же результат, будет ли он последовательным? Или каждый раз при одинаковых входных данных будет выдавать разный результат?

Answer (score 2):

Мы всегда можем посмотреть на почти все в pytnon, зачем гадать?
Проверим сначала хэш-функцию целых чисел:

```
import string
import operator

hash_int = [(i, hash(i)) for i in range(30)]
# сортируем список полученных кортежей по хэшу
sort_hash_int = sorted(hash_int, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for t in sort_hash_int:
    print(f'{t[0]} - hash {t[1]}')

0 - hash 0
1 - hash 1
2 - hash 2
3 - hash 3
4 - hash 4
5 - hash 5
6 - hash 6
7 - hash 7
8 - hash 8
9 - hash 9
10 - hash 10
11 - hash 11
12 - hash 12
13 - hash 13
14 - hash 14
15 - hash 15
16 - hash 16
17 - hash 17
18 - hash 18
19 - hash 19
20 - hash 20
21 - hash 21
22 - hash 22
23 - hash 23
24 - hash 24
25 - hash 25
26 - hash 26
27 - hash 27
28 - hash 28
29 - hash 29
```

Чтож видно - она довольно последовательна.
Давай посмотрим на цифры float.

```
hash_float = [(i/10, hash(i/10)) for i in range(30)]
sort_hash_float = sorted(hash_float, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for t in sort_hash_float:
    print(f'{t[0]} - hash {t[1]}')

0.0 - hash 0
1.0 - hash 1
2.0 - hash 2
0.1 - hash 230584300921369408
1.1 - hash 230584300921369601
2.1 - hash 230584300921369602
1.2 - hash 461168601842738689
0.2 - hash 461168601842738816
2.2 - hash 461168601842739202
2.3 - hash 691752902764107778
0.3 - hash 691752902764108160
1.3 - hash 691752902764108289
1.4 - hash 922337203685477377
2.4 - hash 922337203685477378
0.4 - hash 922337203685477632
0.5 - hash 1152921504606846976
1.5 - hash 1152921504606846977
2.5 - hash 1152921504606846978
0.6 - hash 1383505805528216320
1.6 - hash 1383505805528216577
2.6 - hash 1383505805528216578
0.7 - hash 1614090106449585664
1.7 - hash 1614090106449585665
2.7 - hash 1614090106449586178
2.8 - hash 1844674407370954754
0.8 - hash 1844674407370955264
1.8 - hash 1844674407370955265
1.9 - hash 2075258708292324353
2.9 - hash 2075258708292324354
0.9 - hash 2075258708292324608
```

Последовательность нарушена, но видна некоторая зависимость от цифры после запятой, и "последовательность" не меняется от нескольких запусков программы.
Теперь английский алфавит:

```
hash_ascii = [(c, hash(c)) for c in string.ascii_letters]
sort_hash_ascii = sorted(hash_ascii, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for t in sort_hash_ascii:
    print(f'{t[0]} - hash {t[1]}')

W - hash -9153267238207957297
G - hash -9001094759086774173
b - hash -8734854015206968797
V - hash -8268124510388912222
y - hash -8182369025077419242
Z - hash -8180904979919210189
C - hash -7694848472351893725
g - hash -7261216421159367989
e - hash -6809008879262181373
l - hash -6771811945382922576
P - hash -6092321604697881005
M - hash -6043524160651294542
A - hash -5710642414994430053
r - hash -5113067248557512982
E - hash -5102682317737743073
K - hash -4949739013330198641
p - hash -4807909140446831083
H - hash -4774587340824894941
i - hash -4268741417924833696
z - hash -3954576623916206947
k - hash -3805828122761430396
J - hash -3751902049843500292
B - hash -2478644079121840838
S - hash -1855712552181755138
D - hash -1592483871241666568
a - hash -389073187977273928
n - hash -288963703830889734
f - hash 120277352111170109
F - hash 236135285067325712
U - hash 392228977874898084
Q - hash 734414891688905169
R - hash 1775838682076705170
j - hash 2647993501948249622
O - hash 3257906900986414419
X - hash 3290856389088778655
d - hash 3524312240480631375
w - hash 3665628033941512905
Y - hash 5674525675556245854
h - hash 5722781606122321922
c - hash 5857460755026204507
u - hash 5886111645377928651
m - hash 5919275508930546522
L - hash 6024412459745990564
x - hash 6095112000302699588
q - hash 7423007953334774292
I - hash 7450656751059993712
t - hash 7972802046882223098
T - hash 8113826293047469910
N - hash 8265917239407483442
s - hash 8819528502962714521
o - hash 8854156040387343257
v - hash 9157671329750816605
```

Вот теперь полный хаос, и главное он меняется при каждом запуске функции! Надеюсь эти примеры дали вам какую-то информацию об основной хэш-функции в pytnon. Более подробное описание на неё можно почитать здесь [python-hash-table](https://realpython.com/python-hash-table/) и конечно в документации.